# How to write a test sequence for JSON body?

Tags: json, testing, postman, sequence

I have this 'POST' json body

```
{
    "guid": "{{guid}}",
    "objectId": "{{object_id}}",
    "systemCode": "{{code_of_system}}",
    "callbackURL": "{{callback_url}}",
    "packageType": "{{package_type}}",
    "files":
            [
                {
                    "fileName": "file01.pdf",
                    "documentType": "example"   
                }
            ]
}
```

I want to create a sequence in `"Pre-req."` or `"Tests"` for the `"fileName"` object so it'll automatically change the fileName within the body. For example, I have two files `"file01.pdf"` and `"file02.pdf"`. Is there an option for automatic name changing after I ran the post case - it'll switch from 'file01.pdf' to 'file02.pdf' ?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"fileName": "file{{index}}.pdf"
```

now change index from pre or test script

```
pm.environment.set("index", "2");

or

pm.environment.set("index", pm.environment.get("index")+1);
```

Comment: `pm.environment.set("index", pm.environment.get("index")+1);` this will add +1 each time I run the script right ?

Comment: Yes adds one and stores it to environment